# shortcode - within a shortcode WP PHP HTML

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to know if there is a way for the chocolate to be directed to two different parameters? And I will explain

this shortcode [group skill] => return $skill;

This is the second shortcode [group lang] => return $lang;

I have a group that I opened through ACF and I want to take out a shortcode every time to a different place, to the place intended for it

**This is the original code**

```
<?php 
add_shortcode('group', function ($atts) {
    $group_field = get_field('info_global_course');
    if ($group_field):

        $attributes = shortcode_atts([
            'level_skill' => $group_field[level_skill],
            'lang' =>  $group_field[lang],
            'if_id_true' => $group_field[if_id_true]
        ], $atts);

/* I thought about this way, maybe it's not a rally, but maybe it will give you an idea to help me a little
 *   return $attributes['level_skill'];
 *    return $attributes['lang'];
 */

    endif;
});
?>
```

**editing:**
After failed attempts, I preferred to build the design on top of **HTML** (previously it was built in the form of **Elementor**)

I have the following code:

```
<?php 
/*************************************
 * Returns the values ​​from a certain group of the post
 *************************************/
add_shortcode('group', function ($atts,$shortcode_twoo,$shortcode_three) {
    $group_field = get_field('info_global_course');
    if ($group_field):

        $attributes = shortcode_atts([
            'level_skill' => $group_field[level_skill],
            'lang' =>  $group_field[lang],
            'if_id_true' => $group_field[if_id_true]
        ], $atts);

        
    return '
    <div>
        <div class="level_skill border_bottom">
            <span class="box_left"><i aria-hidden="true" class="far fa-clock"></i> time </span> 
            <span class="box_right">'.$shortcode .'</span>
        </div>
        <div class="video border_bottom">
            <span class="box_left"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-video"></i> Study chapters </span> 
            <span class="box_right">'.$shortcode1.'</span>
        </div>
        <div class="studants border_bottom">
            <span class="box_left"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i> Registered students</span> 
            <span class="box_right">100</span>
        </div>
        <div class="level_skill border_bottom">
            <span class="box_left"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>  level skill</span> 
            <span class="box_right">מתקדמים</span>
        </div>
         <div class="lang border_bottom">
            <span class="box_left"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-globe"></i>language</span> 
            <span class="box_right">עברית</span>
        </div>
        <div class="if_id_true border_bottom">
            <span class="box_left"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-sticky-note"></i> Diploma</span> 
            <span class="box_right">כן</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    ';
    endif;
});
?>
```

The goal is to insert into this array all the shortcodes I will create in the future

**That's why I did:**

```
<?php
     $shortcode = do_shortcode('[time]');
     $shortcode1 = do_shortcode('[chapters]');
?>
```

**or for HTML:**
[time]
[chapters]

But then I get stuck on the same issue of how I insert the various **SHORTCODE** variables

Comment: Seems like you are trying to render/return different data when the attributes are change? can you please elaborate it little more?

Comment: Of course, instead of opening 5-6 SHORTCODEs for each of my dynamic fields, I want to open one and then adjust them to their designated places

Comment: The purpose of `shortcode_atts` is to merge the passed arguments with the default ones. I can't see much sense in using that here. You are not using an attribute name in your given examples, so the passed attribute will be found in `$attr[0]`. So if `$attr[0] == 'skill'` - then you want to return your skill value, and if it is `$attr[0] == 'lang'` instead, then you want to return your lang value ...

Comment: See, in principle you are right, but I couldn't think of another way besides an array, so if you have another way, I would love to know about it

Comment: I changed the wording
If anyone can take a look at how I do it in simple HTML

Comment: _"so if you have another way, I would love to know about it"_ - I basically gave you "pseudo code" in my previous comment already.

Comment: @CBroe
What you told me doesn't reflect what I need, I need to use a nested SHORTCODE and what you said doesn't allow it

Comment: _"The goal is to insert into this array all the shortcodes I will create in the future"_ - the name of the shortcode itself you get passed into your callback function via the third parameter, so if you want to do something different based on that ...

Comment: No idea what you are talking about - where is the "nesting" in what you have shown so far?

Comment: Not displayed for the simple reason that I don't know how to execute a nested SHORTCODE..
What will help me if I take the value and return it?
I need to perform three shortcodes and the two shortcodes have a calculation of the amount of study hours and study chapters and the following is dynamic ACF content for the current post.. -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to everyone who tried to help
I found a nice method to combine all the shortcodes into one shortcode

```
<?php 
    /********************
     * Consolidation of shortcodes
     **********************/
    add_shortcode('total_topics_chapters_group',function() {
        $output = '';
        $output .= do_shortcode('[time]');
        $output .= do_shortcode('[chapters]');
        $output .= do_shortcode('[group]');
        return $output;
    });
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short Code Definition Class (Create the file with desired name and add the code in to the file.

```
class MyPlugin_ShortCodes
{

  
    /**
     * Register the shortcodes for the public-facing side of the site.
     *
     * @since    1.0.0
     */
    public function register_shortcodes()
    {
        add_shortcode('group', array($this, 'shortcode'));
    }

    public function shortcode($attrs, $content = "", $shortcode = "my-plugin")
    {
        $allAttrs = $attrs;
        $attrs = shortcode_atts(array(
            'type' => null,
            'id' => null,
            'code' => null,            
        ), $attrs, $shortcode);

        if ($attrs["type"] != null) {
            try {
                $f = 'do__' . $attrs["type"];

                if (method_exists($this, $f))
                    return $this->$f($attrs, $content, $allAttrs);

                return '[The "type" attribute did not match any known shortcode type. Found: ' . $attrs["type"] . ']';
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                return json_encode($ex->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return "Don't Know what to process!";
    }

    function do__skill($attrs, $content, $allAttrs)
    {

        $html = "Put your skills level here";
        
        return $html;
    }

    function do__lang($attrs, $content, $allAttrs)
    {

        $html = "Do Whateaver you want";
        
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Now Add the below lines to your plugin definition file

```
$plugin_shortcodes = new MyPlugin_ShortCodes();
$this->loader->add_action('init', $plugin_shortcodes, 'register_shortcodes');
```

Shortcodes could be called like...

```
do_shortcode('[group type="skill" id="{$ID}"]');
do_shortcode('[group type="lang" id="{$ID}" code="en"]');
do_shortcode('[group type="xxxx"');
```